# SharePoint 2013 sequential workflow for multiple users

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, visual-studio-2015

I created a sequential workflow in SP2013 using the below link :

https://www.splessons.com/create-multiple-user-assign-task-workflow-sharepoint/#SPLessonPhoto[myGallery]/21/

the workflow creates the tasks for multiple users but as soon as it creates the task it marks it as 'completed'.
My queries are:

- How can we make it 'In progress' until the associated tasks are completed.
- I have a requirement that there could be multiple tasks (2), out of which if anyone approves or completes the task the workflow should mark it as 'completed'. How can I achieve this.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow described in this article should definitely wait for the task to be completed.
The most probable explanation is a flaw in your implementation, and more precisely some bad settings for the `CorrelationToken` and the `TaskId` properties of  both `CreateTask` and `OnTaskChanged` activities. I would check those first.

Comment: I made it wait for the task completion but now I am stuck at one point that how can i mark WF completed if any of the task gets completed. As per my requirement the workflow should stop when any of the 2 users review or approve it. can you please help me

Comment: You may simply add a "Stop workflow" activity (not sure about the name, maybe it's "Complete/terminate the WF") in the a conditionnal branch that checks the conditions you require.